# How can I convert to int array to dictionary?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, int

Do you have any idea how I can do it?

```
 public override IDictionary<int, DateTime> GetList()
     {
         var AdList = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();
         AdList = client.GetAdList(loginTicket); //it returns int array.
         // I've also tried AdList =client.GetAdList(loginTicket).ToDictionary<int, DateTime>();  it doesn't work..
         return AdList;
     }
```

Comment: How're you going to generate dates?

Comment: This function returns the advertisement lists which are posted before the given date (DateTime holds it).Sergio,thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, don't have information about how you're going to get dates, or where do you get em from, but i can suggest some code:

```
public static IDictionary<int, DateTime> GetList()
{
    var AdList = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();
    var intArr = GetAdList(); //get your int[] array or List<int>

    //if method GetAdList() returns List<int> use this line
    intArr.ForEach(a => AdList.Add(a, DateTime.Now));

    //otherwise if method returns int[] array use this line
    Array.ForEach(intArr, a => AdList.Add(a, DateTime.Now)); //populate dictionary with array elements as keys and DateTime.Now as values

    return AdList;
}
```

Comment: Imm, i got "The type arguments for method 'System.Array.ForEach<T>(T[], System.Action<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly." error..

Comment: @Gece updated my answer. Your method returns `List<int>` while you said that it returns `int array`, so you gotta use `List` class method

Comment: GetList returns a dictionary which has the ID (key) and LastUpdateDate (value) Sergio and GetAdList returns an int array. I don't know how can i deal with it. I've tried  `ICollection key = AdArr.Value;` yet when i tried AdList.Keys = key; i got an error which is about "Property or indexer 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,System.DateTime>.Keys' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only" .